# EF Seed not working when data already in database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, orm

First time creating DB and running `Seed` method works fine. It throws error on second run when data is already in the database.

I also noticed that when I assign property to entity, its `PropertyId` is not updated and stays null.

This is my code.

```
protected override void Seed(StreetStats.Data.StreetStatsDbContext context)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

    using (context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            Worker worker = new Worker()
            {
                Name = "Worker 1",
            };

            context.Workers.AddOrUpdate(w => w.Name, worker);
            context.SaveChanges(); //Worker gets Id assigned to the existing worker with the same name in DB

            Job job = new Job()
            {
                Name = "Job 1",                     
                Worker = worker
            };

            context.Jobs.AddOrUpdate(j => j.Name, job);
            context.SaveChanges(); //WorkerId is null for some reason

            MonitoringTask monitoringTask = new MonitoringTask
            {
                Job = job,
                Name = "Task 1"                     
            };

            context.MonitoringTasks.AddOrUpdate(mt => mt.Name, monitoringTask);
            context.SaveChanges(); //Throws exception

            Area area = new Area
            {
                MonitoringTask = monitoringTask,
                Name = "Area 1"                     
            };

            context.Areas.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Name, area);
            context.SaveChanges();

            context.Database.CurrentTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            context.Database.CurrentTransaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This is exception message on third SaveChanges:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.MonitoringTasks_dbo.Jobs_JobId". The conflict occurred in database "StreetStats", table "dbo.Jobs", column 'Id'.

Every FK relation looks like

```
Worker Worker { get; set; }
Int64 WorkerId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the entity state of `job` after its `AddOrUpdate` call in the second run. You can do this like so:

```
Debug.WriteLine(context.Entry(job).State);
```

You'll see that it's `Detached`. Still, if you do ...

```
Debug.WriteLine(context.Jobs.Local.First().Name);
```

... you'll see that in reality the job is attached to the context!

This a [known bug](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2128) in `AddOrUpdate`. The instance that's actually attached to the context is hidden from your method scope, and `job` is a second instance that EF doesn't know of.

That causes all kinds of misery. The job you connect with `monitoringTask` will be seen as a new instance and EF will try to insert it. I'm not sure why you get a foreign key exception (I would have expected a unique key violation) but I think that has to do with primary key column type and whether or not it has an identity specification.

Anyway, the work-around is to do ...

```
context.Workers.AddOrUpdate(w => w.Name, worker);
context.SaveChanges();
worker = context.Workers.Local.Single(w => w.Name == worker.Name);
```

... and so on, for each `AddOrUpdate` call of which you intend to use the objects later. This makes the actually attached (but hidden) objects equal to the ones visible to you.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it. I think I'll just write my own AddOrUpdate extension method.
How did they missed that in tests? It is my first encounter with EF and I found in in first 10 minutes of using it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this also; just add the Id field for each property you are adding in your seed method.

i.e.

```
Worker worker = new Worker()
{
    WorkerId = 1,
    Name = "Worker 1",
};

context.Workers.AddOrUpdate(w => w.Name, worker);
context.SaveChanges();

Job job = new Job()
{
    JobId = 1,
    Name = "Job 1",                     
    Worker = worker.WorkerId
};

context.Jobs.AddOrUpdate(j => j.Name, job);
context.SaveChanges(); //WorkerId is null for some reason

MonitoringTask monitoringTask = new MonitoringTask
{
    MonitoringTaskId = 1,
    Job = job.JobId,
    Name = "Task 1"                     
};

context.MonitoringTasks.AddOrUpdate(mt => mt.Name, monitoringTask);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This worked for me.