# IDbSet<TEntity>.AddOrUpdate does not check if data already exists and inserts duplicate rows

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework v6.1.2 targetting v4.5.2 of the .NET framework and have a LocalDb instance running SQL Server 2014.

I have a table like so, which already has some data like so:

```
Foo
---------
Id    Name
---------
1    Apple
2    Ball
3    Cat
```

I have Entity Framework migrations enabled on this database.

This is the code I have in my seed for this table.

```
namespace MyProject.Models.SeedData
{
    public class FooSeeder : IDataSeeder
    {
        public void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            var foos = new string[]
            {
                "Apple",
                "Ball",
                "Cat"
            };

            context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(foo => new { foo.Name },
                foos.Select(f => new Foo { Name = f }).ToArray()
                );

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I want that if the same Foo.Name exists, it must not add a new row but should simply update the existing row.

However, when I run the seeder, it creates new rows for all the data and thus after running the seed, the table looks like this:

```
Foo
---------
Id    Name
---------
1    Apple
2    Ball
3    Cat
4    Apple
5    Ball
6    Cat
```

Apparently, the call to the [AddOrUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217945%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method isn't working as expected.

Comment: This probably isn't your real code? AddOrUpdate has some issues, but they're not likely to occur in this example.

Comment: @GertArnold This is a simplified version of my real code. Is something wrong with it?

Comment: Well, I can't imagine any problem to occur in this code. I need to see (something that is closer to) the real thing, something that really reproduces the issue.

Comment: In the mean time, you may want to check if [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34405296/861716) could be in play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer as the comments won't allow enough characters to post the sample code. But, as discussed in the comments, this does not reproduce based on the simple scenario described.

Here is a sample app I used to try and reproduce it. Running it several times just results in the expected three results in the database. Perhaps you could post a more complete code listing that demonstrates the issue?

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;

namespace Repro.EF6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new FooContext())
            {
                var foos = new string[]
                {
                "Apple",
                "Ball",
                "Cat"
                };

                context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(foo => new { foo.Name },
                    foos.Select(f => new Foo { Name = f }).ToArray()
                    );

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and my apologies for wasting your time. I found out what the problem was and it turned out to be my fault. The data that was already in the database had the exact same values but each value had a trailing space after it. It was too difficult to track down because in the SQL Server Management Studio GUI, they looked exactly alike. :-)